# Polarion API - get the document revision number

Tags: document, revision, polarion

I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve a newly created document revision number through the Polarion API.

Currently I am trying to branch a source document to a new one but I can't get the associated revision number of the new document branch. This is essential to know because it is possible that multiple users access to the same document branch and I need to script automated changes to the new document (the branch).

I expect there exists an API on documents (in the format project/space/document) from where I can retrieve its head revision number.

As a matter of fact, when I create a new document I get all the new branch document information but not the revision number.
The problem is that as it is generated by Polarion on the creation/modification of any document (mine if the new branched one). I am worried to be able to manage this new document - including its own new revision I can't know at this point.

In addition, I wonder if it is possible to keep track of the new document revision with a script and during several different steps change the document revision automatically.